# Strech a portion of image only

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div where only a part of background would stretch if the div gets bigger.

Situation :

- My image can be divided in 3 (1: upper part, 2 : middle part, 3 : lower part).
- My div is Ypx long where Y > Image 1.height + Image3.height
- My div has the same width as the image

Request :

- Image 1 and 3 should always appear.
- Image 2 should stretch according to the div size.

Example image :

[image: My problem]

Comment: well your link doesn't explain well your question, maybe define your header and footer as absolute and your body will change, did you try that??and next time provide some code please in order to receive help

Comment: I don't see what code I could provide except <did>Lorem Ipsum</div>... You talk about header and footer, so you suggest that I do 3 vertical divs ? The problem is that I want the content to be over the 3 parts of the image, not only in the middle div.

Comment: well as your request said i was that the image 2 should stretch, but with your clarification the thing that you want is that your header, body and footer rezise??that's what i percive with your answer, isn't it??or try to search another link that shows wath you are looking for :-D

Comment: Edited, Hope it's more clear !

Comment: Split it into 3 images.  Create a container div with two divs for the upper and lower elements inside it.  Position those divs absolutely to the top and bottom and set the appropriate background images.  Set the background image of the container itself to be the middle image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `border-image` to achieve this without extra elements in your HTML. Apply the border to a `:before` pseudo-element with `z-index` of -1 to push it behind the main content. Set the top and bottom border widths to the height of the red and blue stripes (67px in this example), and left and right borders to 0. Use `fill` in the `border-image` to use the middle of the image as a background. And use `border-box` for `box-sizing` to have the borders inside the element.

```
.flagbg {
    position:relative;
    width:213px;
}
.flagbg:before {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-width:67px 0 67px 0;
    border-image:url('flag.png') 67 0 67 0 fill repeat stretch;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9e3T/ - you can edit the text in the result pane and see it resize dynamically

Comment: Great answer but how can I put this inside a div ? See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9e3T/5/ : The image disappears behind the parent div (even if I try to set a z-index:-2 for the parent div)

Comment: `z-index` only works on `absolute` or `relative`ly positioned elements. So you can make the parent div `position:relative` or apply a positive `z-index` to the `.flag` div. Example of the first here http://jsfiddle.net/L9e3T/6/

Comment: Thanks! But then it is not possible to select or click the text anymore (you can see it in your fiddle), is there a solution to that ?